# Design improvement - C

Tags: design, c, refactoring, multithreading, linux-kernel

Below is the design, that is implemented similar to design used in  `Linux/net/socket.c`.

Below design provide `List` abstraction,

### [image]

where, `list.h` provides `List` interface, show [here](https://github.com/shamhub/Computing/blob/master/design2Code/list/list.h)

> *Background:*
>
> Reason to implement `List` abstraction in this approach is to consider as a **prototype** inspired from `Linux/net/socket.c` design, where **any one** of the multiple protocol family implementations(like `net/ipv4/af_inet.c` or `net/unix/af_unix.c`/..) is available on invoking `socket(AF_INET | AF_UNIX | AF_XYZ,,)` api.
>
> This **prototype** would help understand implementing snmp library that talks to multiple network elements(Router/Switch/Server) using snmp protocol.

Above design(shown in above image) is an analogy to `Linux/net/socket.c`as shown in this code [here](https://github.com/shamhub/Computing/tree/master/design2Code/list) with a  **slight difference** in linking time(linker phase) unlike linking implementations in `Linux/net/socket.c` happens at loading phase by overriding `_init()` run-time code in  implementation(say `af_inet.c`) and  invoking `sock_register()`

To further improve this analogy,

Am thinking on improving design(shown in above image), that can allow `createList(ARRAY_IMPL)` get called from `fileIO/fileReading.c`(for its own purpose) and   `createList(LINKED_LIST_IMPL)` get called from `ST/implUsingList.c`(for its own purpose).

With current design(shown in above image), it breaks the purpose, as it works with **any one** implementation(say `arrayImpl.c`) linked at linker phase.

*Reason:* `ListHandler *handler = NULL;` is global variable defined in `virtualImplLayer.c`and gets over-ridden on every call to `createList(ImplType)`, as shown in this code [here](https://github.com/shamhub/Computing/blob/master/design2Code/list/virtualImplLayer.c)

My question:

How to enhance this prototype design to pick multiple implementations for client scenario(shown in image)? Does it require multi-threading at virtual implementation layer??

Comment: Don't use a global variable for handler. Store hander as a list member.

Comment: @Basilevs OK. So, if its is non-global, then every client  should pass  `ImplType` ( `enum {ARRAY_IMPL, LINKD_LIST_IMPL}ImplType`) to pick their implementation, which makes code cumbersome and not good abstraction

Comment: No, as list instance would incapsulate it's type

Comment: @Basilevs  As you said,  `List` instance can encapsulate `ImplType`. But If `List` type maintains information about `ImplType`, then how would `virtualImplLayer.c` would know the details of `List` type sitting in `arrayImpl.c`/`linkListImpl.c`? `List` type details are hidden from `virtualImplLayer.c`. If details  are exposed, then it is bad abstraction

Comment: It only needs to know about handler field. If this field is first in the structure, exact structure of other fields is irrelevant. Use first few fields of your list to carry type information. Make them mandatory for all list kinds.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1114349/125562 see C inheritance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to implement a virtual table.
See how it's done in https://stackoverflow.com/q/3113583/125562

Basic idea is to store all methods required to interact with a structure as its fields.

There are other examples. Google C vtable.

Comment: If I make `ListImplType` available in `listHandler.h` that instance is populated in every implementation(in the beginning). Do I need to invoke `findImplType()` in `virtualImplLayer.c`? But which implementation to call? `virtualImplLayer.c` has no info about it

Comment: You are asking for implementation details here. Please see linked question for them. They are off-topic for this site. You don't need to find any type information, because it is immediately available in the object's first field.

Comment: Only createList() interface is receiving impltype information from the client program. How can other interface know the impltype?

Comment: It is accessible as structure field.

Comment: Yes but only for on e interface

Comment: Yes, one interface, arbitrary number of implementations. Implementation would know specifics of data structure and handle operations in a type dependent way. Client would call interface methods to invoke implementation. This way, client code would be unaware of concrete implementation, but can use the object nevertheless. Do you want another kind of type information?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51448/discussion-between-overexchange-and-basilevs).

Comment: Am still not clear, how the link that talks about vtable implementation in your answer solve the problem?